# Duvida em manipulação de variáveis em C

Tags: c

O código a seguir usa a estrutura de decisão para escolher o comando condizente com a operação escolhida pelo usuário.

Como eu conseguiria simplificar isso? Tentei modularizar a instrução `printf` mas não consegui.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char operador = ' ';
    float valor1, valor2;
    printf("Entre com um tipo de operacao a ser realizada (+,-,*,/), o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
    scanf("%c %f %f", &operador, &valor1, &valor2);
    if (operador == '+'){
        printf("Resultado da soma %.2f", valor1+valor2);
    }
    else if (operador =='-'){
        printf("Resultado da subtracao %.2f", valor1-valor2);
    }
    else if (operador =='*'){
        printf("Resultado da multiplicacao %.2f", valor1*valor2);
    }
    else{
        printf("Resultado da divisao %.2f", valor1/valor2);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system ("pause");

}
```

Como ficaria Modularizada?

```
printf("Digite um tipo de operacao(+,-,*,/) e em seguida o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
scanf("%c %d %d", &o, &x, &y);
    if(o=='+'){
        op=x+y;

          }
    else if (o=='-'){
        op=x-y;

          }
    else if (o=='*'){
        op=x*y;

          }
    else{
        op=x/y;

        }

    if(op==x+y && op==x-y && op==x*y  &&  op==x/y){
              printf("O resultado e:%d",op );
```

Comment: Na minha opinião, já está simples o suficiente e não precisa mudar. Claro, alguém até pode sugerir coisas complicadas, como criar um mapeamento de operações -> função/mensagem, ou dizer que "_é melhor usar um `switch`_" (não é), mas tudo isso é querer complicar à toa, não precisa disso. Aliás, por que vc acha que está complicado?

Comment: Eu nao queria ter q repetir aquele tanto de printf pra cada decisão. To testando ideias e a minha era modulara-la. Ficaria assim mais ou menos mas nao esta dando certo...

Comment: https://ideone.com/UZKqP7

Comment: Eu coloquei na pergunta como que fiucaria

Comment: Realmente complicou nesse caso, mas muito obrigado por iluminar minha ideia!KKK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se só quer fazer um `printf` no final, então tem que pegar todas as informações que mudam (no caso, o nome da operação e o resultado) e setá-las de acordo com a operação escolhida. No final, você imprime o resultado:

```
char operador;
float valor1, valor2;
printf("Entre com um tipo de operacao a ser realizada (+,-,*,/), o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
scanf("%c %f %f", &operador, &valor1, &valor2);

// o nome da operação e o resultado variam conforme a operação escolhida
char *operacao = NULL;
float resultado;
if (operador == '+') {
    operacao = "soma";
    resultado = valor1 + valor2;
} else if (operador == '-') {
    operacao = "subtracao";
    resultado = valor1 - valor2;
} else if (operador == '*') {
    operacao = "multiplicacao";
    resultado = valor1 * valor2;
} else if (operador == '/') {
    operacao = "divisao";
    resultado = valor1 / valor2;
}

if (operacao != NULL)
    printf("Resultado da %s: %.2f\n", operacao, resultado);
else // pode ser digitada uma operação inválida, então trate este caso também 
    printf("Operação inválida\n");
```

Repare que também tratei o caso da operação digitada ser inválida. No seu código, qualquer coisa que não fosse `+`, `-` ou `*` caía na divisão.